# Stopping/Pausing a sound that is set to repeat forever in SpriteKit Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, sprite-kit, swift3

I'm having an issue and would really like it if someone could help out, basically I have a sequence of two sounds that are set to repeat forever. However, I want it so that I can trigger the sound to stop.

All I really need to know is:

In Swift 3 SpriteKit, what code do I use to stop, or pause, a repeating sequence of sounds indefinitely?

Edit: I was using SKActions to play the sounds, the issue has now been solved.

Comment: need more info, what are you using to actually play the sound

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always good practice to show some code on stack overflow, with your current question we can only take guesses.

If you are using SKActions for sound you can give the repeat action a key and remove that action later. Create the key like so

```
 class GameScene: SKScene {

       let soundKey = "RemoveSoundKey" // this avoids typos
 }
```

and than change your action to this

```
 let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(YOURSOUNDACTION)
 run(repeatAction, withKey: soundKey)
```

Than you can say

```
 removeAction(forKey: soundKey)
```

when you want to stop the repeat action.

Note: If you run the action on a node e.g

```
 player.run(repeatAction...)
```

dont forget to call the remove action on the node

```
 player.removeAction(forKey: soundKey)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry about that, I am using SKActions, and this helped a lot. (Also I was rushing a little while writing the question) Thanks.